# Samsung i780 networking issues

Tags: wireless-networking, internet

So I have a Samsung i780 mobile phone and I would like to use the internet through my wireless router. I have connected to it. I got an IP address. My laptop is also connected to the same wireless network and I can ping the mobile phone and I get answer.
When I open the internet explorer and enter an address it says that it cannot connect to the internet. I have googled very much, but can't find the problem. What do you think, what is the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Enter your DNS on your mobile phone.

Comment: But I tried to enter the ip address of the website and it doesn't work either, but I try to enter a dns. Thanks!

Comment: after entering IP address you will only be able to join to network. but without default gateway and DNS you will not able to browse internet.

Comment: No, it's not working :( Any other ideas?